# Get the "class" attribute of an object split into an array of strings

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, string, class

Preamble: I'm Italian, sorry for my bad English.

So this is the question:

considering an HTML object like this:

```
<div id="myDiv" class="c1 c2 c3 c4 c5"></div>
```

how can I get an array of strings, using jquery, from the "class" attribute of the "div" element?

Example:

```
var a = $('#myDiv').getClassArray(); //Not working,just an example

return a;  //[c1,c2,c3,c4,c5]
```

I thought I could read the "class" attribute and then split the string, but it seems too verbose, I wondered if there was a shorter and more elegant method.

Comment: Don't u think u missed # in $('myDiv').getClassArray();

Comment: I dont think there is better way than split string class

Comment: You could always make a plugin to do this, if it is a frequent need.

Comment: @ameyarote I forget the '#' character, you're right, but it was just a sample code

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need `#` for id [selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) and use [split()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) to get array from string.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/zqN2G/)**

```
var a = $('#myDiv').attr('class').split(' ');
```

You can iterate through array using jQuery [jQuery.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) of for loop.

```
var a = $('#myDiv').attr('class').split(' ');

$.each(a, function(index, item){
    alert(item);
});​
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `$('#myDiv')` instead of `$('myDiv')`?

Comment: I forget the '#' character,i know, you're right, but it was just a sample code

Comment: This solution doesn't account for multiple spaces between class names. `$('#myDiv').attr('class').replace(/\s+/g, ' ').split(' ');` would take this in to account.

Comment: No worries, you can will have array in a

Answer (score 3):

The new standard [`classList`](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#dom-classlist) property would allow such easy access on DOM elements (e.g., through `$('#myDiv')[0].classList` in jQuery), but it is not universally implemented. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.classList) for documentation on this standard or [here](http://caniuse.com/#search=classlist) for current browser support.

Providing such functionality as a shim was proposed for jQuery in [bug 7378](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/7378), but was rejected.

You could however, get such support via a shim, such as perhaps https://github.com/eligrey/classList.js

**Updated**: A demo with the shim is at http://jsfiddle.net/brettz9/WWs5B/1/

Comment: This seems to be interesting ... unfortunately, considering that has bugs, I can not use it,  but could be useful in the future,tx!

Comment: What has bugs? If you are talking about jQuery, that is just a feature request (which was denied), not a bug. What I am talking about is a feature not yet supported in all browsers, but if you add a script tag for the classList.js shim, it should let you use it as I described.

Comment: I've updated the answer to link to this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/brettz9/WWs5B/1/

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you try this: http://jsfiddle.net/egZ2z/

```
var cls = $('#myDiv').attr('class');
var n = cls.split(' ')
alert(n);
```