# getting the class attribute value from button having multiple classes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making the simple site but stuck on the very simple concept that is to take the values from class attribute value from button having multiple classes.When I am trying to use `attr()`, It shows string having multiple classes.My problem is how to access it???, The code of this is given below.

HTML CODE

```
<button id="view" class="cc btn btn-primary">View</button>
```

JS CODE

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('button').click(
function()
{
$id=$(this).attr('id');
$class=$(this).attr('class');////////cc btn btn-primary but i want only `cc`
}
)
</script>
```

Comment: It works as expected!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the "class" attribute of an object split into an array of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14156237/get-the-class-attribute-of-an-object-split-into-an-array-of-strings)

Answer (score 0):

@nancy harigton, method I usually go with is to split the classes into an array, like so: https://jsfiddle.net/90dty5oo/8/

```
$('button').click(function() {
    var myClass= $(this).attr('class');

    myFirstClass = myClass.split(" ");

    alert(myFirstClass[0]);
});
```

You also do not need the first line inside the function regarding the ID.

---

## ES6 Update

Here's the ES6 version of the code using arrow functions and template literals:

```
document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const myClass = button.getAttribute('class');
    const [myFirstClass] = myClass.split(' ');
    alert(myFirstClass);
  });
});
```

Comment: @allenski, ya It is working but the problem is how to access it? Is it an array? It is showing a string.....

Comment: @nancy, do you just need one of the classes? or all of them

Comment: I want only cc class string for attr comparison

Comment: Split into an array. I have updated my answer for you :)

Answer (score 0):

You almost there.

This `$(this).attr('class')` returns a string with the whole set of class names.

An alternative is splitting the class names using this regex `/\s+/` and get the desired class name.

Use this regex `/\s+/` to split the classnames with these formats: `cc     btn btn-primary`, or `cc     btn      btn-primary`, or `cc btn btn-primary`, Etc,.

```js
$('button').click(
  function() {
    //$id = $(this).attr('id');
    var classNames = $(this).attr('class').split(/\s+/);
    console.log(classNames)
    console.log(classNames.length ? classNames[0] : '');

    //Check is classname 'cc' exists.
    console.log(this.classList.contains('cc')); // Native attribute classList.        
    console.log($(this).hasClass('cc')); // jQuery function hasClass.
  }
)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="view" class="cc      btn      btn-primary">Click this View</button>
```